# Error while changing the status of render elements for the layers created in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I have written a python script that creates render layers in Maya for the lighters. The script creates the 4 basic layers as shown in the picture below. The script also changes the render settings on each layer. [image]
I got the following error while trying to change the status of render elements for chrShadow and occ layers.

```
# RuntimeError: # Error occurred during execution of MEL script
file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2013/vray/scripts/vrayCreateRenderElementsTab.mel line    453: Object 'listAdded' not found.
```

After creating each layer, the script changes the render settings accordingly. FOllwoing is the code where it tries to change the render elements.

```
    mel.eval("unifiedRenderGlobalsWindow")

    render_elements = cmds.ls(type="VRayRenderElement")

    if "Beauty" in current_layer:
        for passes in render_elements:
            mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 1")

    elif "Shadow" in current_layer:
        for passes in render_elements:
            if "Shadow" in passes:
                mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 1")
            else:
                mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 0")

    elif "occ" in current_layer:
        for passes in render_elements:
            if "vrayRE_Extra_Tex" in passes:
                mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 1")
            elif "vrayRE_Velocity" in passes:
                mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 1")
            else:
                mel.eval("listAddedPressed " + str(passes) + " 0")
```

For chrShadow layer the following setting is required: [image] and for occ layer follwoing setting is required: [image].
If I just run this code separately later it works sometimes but mostly I get this error. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'evalDeferred()' command. 
Maya doesn't refresh and can't change parameters in passes you just have created.

example :

```
> cmds.createNode( 'renderPass', name='ZDepth' )
> cmds.evalDeferred("""cmds.setRenderPassType( 'ZDepth', type='CAMZ'
> )""")
```

Comment: I have been looking at the commands you have mentioned above. I still haven't found the solution. Could you please elaborate relating to my script.